# How can a border be set programatically in Google Closure

Tags: javascript, google-closure-library

I'm just getting started with Google Closure, and am trying to customize the spacing between controls in a `goog.ui.Dialog`. As an example, the default buttons in the `goog.ui.Dialog.ButtonSet` are a bit close together:

[image]

From the FireFox Debugger, I can navigate to the component and manually change the border, like this:

[image]

This gives the desired result. The dialog now looks like this:

[image]

I've tried changing the margin programmatically with:

```
  var okButton = dialog.getButtonSet().getButton( goog.ui.Dialog.DefaultButtonKeys.OK );
  okButton.style.marginRightWidth = 8;
  okButton.style.marginRight = 8;
```

but these values won't change, and also can't be changed from the debugger.

How do I go about changing this value on the fly? Or is that even possible--do I really need to change the underlying style sheet to accomplish this?

Comment: Did you mean to set marginRight rather than borderRightWidth?

Comment: Yes--thanks. But that doesn't make a change, either. I tried a lot of combinations, and this just doesn't seem to be a viable way to change the dialog. I've edited the answer to reflect the correct variable, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to edit the spacing is to drop back to straight JavaScript, ignoring the Closure classes. The debugger shows this when the margin is changed manually in the debugger in the debugger:

```
<button style="margin-right: 8px;" disabled="" class="goog-buttonset-default" name="ok">OK</button>
```

Following that example, this code programmatically changes the spacing:

```
var okButton = dialog.getButtonSet().getButton( goog.ui.Dialog.DefaultButtonKeys.OK );
okButton.style = 'margin-right: 8px;';
```